# Turn off “unreachable code after return statement” warning

Tags: firefox, return, gecko, web-console

In JavaScript development, I frequently return from execution to have an inartificial breakpoint:

```js
var args = arguments;
return console.log(args); // debug
criticalProcessing(args);
```

Chrome and others are okay with it, but unfortunately for debugging in Firefox:

> Starting with Gecko 40 (Firefox 40 / Thunderbird 40 / SeaMonkey 2.37), a warning is shown in the console if unreachable code is found after a [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

Firefox’ `about:config` provides quite some flags to adjust the development environment. Sadly, I didn’t find a corresponding setting (nor a solution elsewhere).

**Is there a way to turn of the “unreachable code after return statement” warning?**

Comment: This is a problem because some libraries like bluebird optimize for Chrome and putting an eval after the return statement makes the V8 engine run faster.

Comment: @user2867288 can you show maybe any proof on this? We are facing the same issue but require some citation before closing bugtickets for the customer - but I fail to find any.

Comment: @ForestG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987896/how-does-bluebirds-util-tofastproperties-function-make-an-objects-properties

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know of getting around this warning is to put a condition that's always true in the return line:

```
function myFun() {
     var args = arguments;

     if (1) return console.log(args);

    // unreachable code goes here
    criticalProcessing(args);

}
```