# Adding a constructor prototype to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, extending

I have several javascript objects like this:

```
var object = {
    name: "object name",
    description: "object description",
    properties: [
        { name: "first", value: "1" },
        { name: "second", value: "2" },
        { name: "third", value: "3" }
    ]
};
```

Now I wanted to change these objects to smarter objects (adding some methods etc).
At first I made a constructor function like this:

```
SmartObject = function( object ){

    this.name = object.name;

    this.description = object.description;

    this.properties = object.properties;

};

SmartObject.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getDescription = function(){
    return this.description;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getProperies = function(){
    return this.properties;
};
```

And then I used this constructor to change my object to a `SmartObject` instance like this:

```
var smartObject = new SmartObject( object );
```

This seems the proper Object Oriented javascript code to do this, but this feels so overly complicated since all I actually want to do is add some methods and now I copy all properties from my `object` to my `SmartObject` in the constructor function.

***In this example there are only 3 properties and some simple methods, but in my project there are several dozens of (nested) properties and much more complex methods.***

So then I tried this:

```
object.__proto__ = SmartObject.prototype;
```

And this seems to result in exactly the same result and seems much easier (check **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/uq0psLyx/)** for this example).

Is this a proper and acceptable way to add the prototype to my object? Or **is this** breaking object oriented patterns and **considered bad practice** and should I continue doing like I did (using the constructor).

Or is there maybe another more acceptable way to add the methods to my existing object without pulling it through the constructor function?

---

**Note.** I tried to find such example on StackOverflow, but when I search I always end up in examples extending the prototype of existing javascript classes. If there is such question feel free to mark this as a duplicate and I will close my question again.

Comment: don't change object prototypes after creating said object. It's going to kill the compiler's ability to optimize your code. See [MDNs nice warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: Thanks for the edit of your comment... The link is helpful.

Comment: Have you considered using [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)? Put your desired method in another object `methods = { getName : function() {}, etc:etc}` and then `Object.assign(object, methods)`.

Comment: Here's the fiddle demo with two distinct objects: https://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/uq0psLyx/1/

Comment: @nnnnnn `assignObject = Object.assign( new SmartObject(), object );` doesn't work since the constructor tries to access the properties of an argument that I don't pass. I could reqork the constructor, but I wonder if that would be faster then using the constructor directly?

Comment: Read my comment again. It doesn't use the constructor at all, or the prototype, I suggested a `methods` object to hold all your methods, and then `Object.assign()` to copy the methods into *any* object.

Comment: @nnnnnn I read the comment before you updated, I will look again. Thanks!

Comment: MDN covers [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) Suggests `object1.prototype = Object.create(SmartObject.prototype)` ...interesting.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think that will consume more memory then using a constructor and a prototype.

Comment: It will create one instance of each function, but multiple references to them. So yes, more memory, but not tonnes of memory - how many objects do your expect to have? The trade-off is extreme simplicity, which is what I thought you wanted... Or you could do what you had in your comment and set the constructor to have no arguments and no body.

Comment: @nnnnnn Several 100 objects. I need a simpler alternative with the same result, meaning a prototyped object as a result.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the `Object.assign()` suggestion together with `Object.create()` it combined to a nice solution!

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: No it doesn't. That's when `object1` is a constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting plain objects to function instances (“classes”) in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11810028/1048572)?

Answer (score 11):

As I previously mentioned, changing an object's prototype is going to have a severe impact on your code's performance. (*tbh, I've never taken the time to measure the impact*). [This MDN page explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

However, if you're issue is about boilerplate, you could easily create a generic factory for your objects, such as:

```
function genericFactory(proto, source) {
    return Object.keys(source).reduce(function(target, key) {
        target[key] = source[key];
        return target;
    }, Object.create(proto));
}
```

And now you can use it by passing your `SmartObject.prototype` and `object` as arguments like this:

```
var smartObject = genericFactory(SmartObject.prototype, object);
```

Comment: Still something strange, check [here in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/uq0psLyx/2/), it outputs target 3 times in the factory when I add a console.log, should only happen once right?

Comment: Reduce is an accumulator. It loops over an array's values (keys, in this case) - `Object.keys()` creates an array of an object's own property names. Your object is instantiated with 3 properties (keys), so reduce will loop 3 times to build your instance, but genericFactory will only return once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but because of this it will be 3 times as slow right? This can maybe be optimized this so it only gets called the last time...

Comment: I would recommend to avoid optimization until you - know - you need it (*i.e. avoid premature  optimization*). Top of mind, a way to "optimize" the above would be to use a loop instead of the function callback overhead of `reduce()`. In any case, the perf. gains will be minimal unless you have thousands of objects to instantiate at once.

Comment: This is a good solution, but note that it only does a shallow copy of `source`, which may or may not matter.

Comment: I don't know why you think this is the case but mutating __proto__ doesn't make things slow and haven't done so for a while. In fact when you assign something as __proto__ to an object engines like v8 optimize it immediately.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum as I've mentioned, I've never experienced the issue myself. I'm merely relating to the statements made on MDN, which is generally considered a good javascript reference

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Are you sure of that? [It certainly used to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572). Assigning to `__proto__` right after the object creation might not be a problem, but assigning to an object that already was used repeatedly elsewhere seems to be.

Comment: @Bergi if you're interested I go through the code that v8 runs when setting a prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987896/how-does-bluebirds-util-tofastproperties-function-make-an-objects-properties/24989927#24989927 - but generally check `OptimizeAsPrototype`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It doesn't appear to be a problem with the object that is used *asPrototype*, but rather with the object whose [[prototype]] is set.

Comment: @Bergi oh, it will confuse the compiler initially for sure since it'd have to dump a bunch of related data - but the JIT will eventually catch on when it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the `Object.create()` from **@SebastienDaniel** his answer and **@bloodyKnuckles** his comment and the `Object.assign()` method suggested by **@nnnnnn** in his comment I managed with the following simple code to do exactly what I wanted:

```
var smartObject = Object.assign( Object.create( SmartObject.prototype ), object );
```

Check [the updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/uq0psLyx/4/)

Answer (score 2):

> So then I tried this:
>
> ```
> object.__proto__ = SmartObject.prototype;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Is this a proper and acceptable way to add the prototype to my object? Or is this breaking object oriented patterns and considered bad practice and should I continue doing like I did (using the constructor).

I recommend against it, because:

1. Changing the prototype of an object after-the-fact ruins its performance in current JavaScript engines.
2. It's unusual, and thus makes your code a bit alien to anyone else you might have maintain it.
3. It's browser-specific; the `__proto__` property is only defined in an Appendix to the JavaScript spec, and only for browsers (the spec does require browsers to implement it, though). The non-browser-specific way is `Object.setPrototypeOf(object, SmartObject.prototype);` but see #1 and #2.

You see concerned that it's redundant or repetitive, either at the coding level or at the memory level (I'm not sure). It isn't if you embrace your `SmartObject` from the beginning rather than creating `object` first and then adding the smarts later:

```
var SmartObject = function(name, description, properties) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.properties = properties;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getDescription = function(){
    return this.description;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getProperies = function(){
    return this.properties;
};

var object = new SmartObject(
    "object name",
    "object description",
    [
        { name: "first", value: "1" },
        { name: "second", value: "2" },
        { name: "third", value: "3" }
    ]
);

var anotherObject = new SmartObject(
    /*...*/
);

var yetAnotherObject = new SmartObject(
    /*...*/
);
```

or better yet, with ES2015 (which you can use today with a transpiler like Babel):

```
class SmartObject {
    constructor() {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    getProperies(){
        return this.properties;
    }
}

let object = new SmartObject(
    "object name",
    "object description",
    [
        { name: "first", value: "1" },
        { name: "second", value: "2" },
        { name: "third", value: "3" }
    ]
);


let anotherObject = new SmartObject(
    /*...*/
);

let yetAnotherObject = new SmartObject(
    /*...*/
);
```

---

You've said that you can't embrace `SmartObject` from the beginning because they're coming from a JSON source. In that case, you can incorporate your `SmartObject` into the JSON parsing using a *reviver* function:

```
var objects = JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === "object" && v.name && v.description && v.properties) {
        v = new SmartObject(v.name, v.description, v.properties);
    }
    return v;
});
```

While that does mean that the objects are first created and then *re*created, creating objects is a very cheap operation; here's an example showing the time difference when parsing 20k objects with and without a reviver:

```js
var json = '[';
for (var n = 0; n < 20000; ++n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    json += ',';
  }
  json += '{' +
    '   "name": "obj' + n + '",' +
    '   "description": "Object ' + n + '",' +
    '   "properties": [' +
    '       {' +
    '           "name": "first",' +
    '           "value": "' + Math.random() + '"' +
    '       },' +
    '       {' +
    '           "name": "second",' +
    '           "value": "' + Math.random() + '"' +
    '       }' +
    '    ]' +
    '}';
}
json += ']';

var SmartObject = function(name, description, properties) {
  this.name = name;
  this.description = description;
  this.properties = properties;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getDescription = function() {
  return this.description;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getProperies = function() {
  return this.properties;
};

console.time("parse without reviver");
console.log("count:", JSON.parse(json).length);
console.timeEnd("parse without reviver");

console.time("parse with reviver");
var objects = JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
  if (typeof v === "object" && v.name && v.description && v.properties) {
    v = new SmartObject(v.name, v.description, v.properties);
  }
  return v;
});
console.log("count:", objects.length);
console.timeEnd("parse with reviver");
console.log("Name of first:", objects[0].getName());
```

On my machine, it roughly doubles the time, but we're talking ~60ms to ~120ms, so in absolute terms it's nothing to worry about — and that's for 20k objects.

---

Alternately, you could *mix in* your methods rather than having a prototype:

```
// The methods to mix in
var smartObjectMethods = {
    getName() {
      return this.name;
    },
    getDescription() {
      return this.description;
    },
    getProperies() {
      return this.properties;
    }
};
// Remember their names to make it faster adding them later
var smartObjectMethodNames = Object.keys(smartObjectMethods);

// Once we have the options, we update them all:
objects.forEach(function(v) {
    smartObjectMethodNames.forEach(function(name) {
       v[name] = smartObjectMethods[name];
    });
});
```

ES2015 has `Object.assign` which you could use instead of `smartObjectMethodNames` and the inner `forEach`:

```
// Once we have the options, we update them all:
objects.forEach(function(v) {
    Object.assign(v, smartObjectMethods);
});
```

Either way, its ***slightly*** less memory-efficient because each of the objects ends up having its own `getName`, `getDescription`, and `getProperties` properties (the functions aren't duplicated, they're shared, but the properties to refer to them are duplicated). That's extremely unlikely to be a problem, though.

Here's an example with 20k objects again:

```js
var json = '[';
for (var n = 0; n < 20000; ++n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    json += ',';
  }
  json += '{' +
    '   "name": "obj' + n + '",' +
    '   "description": "Object ' + n + '",' +
    '   "properties": [' +
    '       {' +
    '           "name": "first",' +
    '           "value": "' + Math.random() + '"' +
    '       },' +
    '       {' +
    '           "name": "second",' +
    '           "value": "' + Math.random() + '"' +
    '       }' +
    '    ]' +
    '}';
}
json += ']';

var smartObjectMethods = {
    getName() {
      return this.name;
    },
    getDescription() {
      return this.description;
    },
    getProperies() {
      return this.properties;
    }
};
var smartObjectMethodNames = Object.keys(smartObjectMethods);

console.time("without adding methods");
console.log("count:", JSON.parse(json).length);
console.timeEnd("without adding methods");

console.time("with adding methods");
var objects = JSON.parse(json);
objects.forEach(function(v) {
  smartObjectMethodNames.forEach(function(name) {
     v[name] = smartObjectMethods[name];
  });
});
console.log("count:", objects.length);
console.timeEnd("with adding methods");

if (Object.assign) { // browser has it
  console.time("with assign");
  var objects = JSON.parse(json);
  objects.forEach(function(v) {
    Object.assign(v, smartObjectMethods);
  });
  console.log("count:", objects.length);
  console.timeEnd("with assign");
}

console.log("Name of first:", objects[0].getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot *"embrace my `SmartObject` from the beginning"*, the question is just an example in real life the objects are loaded from a JSON source...

Comment: @Wilt: Ah! In that case, you can use a JSON "reviver" function during parsing. Sadly I'm running out the door, but I'll update with an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Given your object is same as SmartObject in properties you might come up with things like this;

```js
var obj = {
    name: "object name",
    description: "object description",
    properties: [
        { name: "first", value: "1" },
        { name: "second", value: "2" },
        { name: "third", value: "3" }
    ]
}, 
SmartObject = function( object ){

    this.name = object.name;

    this.description = object.description;

    this.properties = object.properties;

};

SmartObject.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getDescription = function(){
    return this.description;
};

SmartObject.prototype.getProperties = function(){
    return this.properties;
};
obj.constructor = SmartObject;
obj.__proto__ = obj.constructor.prototype;
console.log(obj.getName());
```

Ok the `__proto__` property is now included in the ECMAScript standard and safe to use. However there is also the `Object.setPrototypeOf()` object method that can be utilized in the same fashion. So you might as well do like `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, obj.constructor.prototype)` in the place of `obj.__proto__ = obj.constructor.prototype;`

Comment: My question was whether this solution is considered bad practice. Your answer is simply repeating the `obj.__proto__ = ...` solution from my question.

Comment: From ES6 on `__proto__` is now within the standard. So should be safe. Yet you still have to assign the constructor properly as well for a proper relationship between your object and SmartObject constructor. (like `obj.constructor = SmartObject;`). Another way is to use `obj.setPrototypeOf(obj.constructor.prototype)` method but i believe now it's exactly doing what `obj.__proto__ = obj.constructor.prototype` does.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you would add what you wrote in your comment to the answer.

Comment: Sorry my comment with `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is not correct since it is an Object method not an Object.prototype method so in your case it should be invoked like `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, obj.constructor.prototype)`