# Surrogate instance changing classes when creating prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

So i'm trying to setup prototypal inheritance using the surrogate method and I have run into a behavior that seems weird for me. Here are my classes:

```
function Animal(name) { 
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function() { 
    console.log("mmm... food...")
};

function Dog(name) { 
    this.name = name 
};

var Surrogate = function() {}
Surrogate.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

Now, I want to setup Animal as the base class. If I make an instance of Surrogate:

[image]

The browser console says that s is an instance of Surrogate.

However, when I set Dog class's prototype to the instance of Surrogate:

[image]

It becomes an instance of Animal? Why is this happening? Is this correct or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: Surrogate is an instance of Animal, so it follows that Dog should also be an instance of Animal to the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using the surrogate method

Protip: Use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for this which has been standard for a decade now :-)

> It becomes an instance of Animal?

No. It's still exactly the same object and no functionality changed. It's an `instanceof Animal` just like it had been before.

The `Animal {}` you see in the console is a custom display choice of the debugger.

> Why is this happening?

My guess would be that you see a side effect of an [internal optimisation that occurs when an object is assigned as the `.prototype` of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987896/1048572), which is observable in the debugger only.