# Assign and immediately delete property

Tags: javascript

I am no javascript programmer and am totally puzzled by what this code does and what it is used for:

```
function map(x) {
    x = Object.create(null);
    x.x = 0;
    delete x.x;
    return x;
}
```

It's part of what you get when using the *dart2js* compiler.

I'm not trying to understand the whole context, but what does assigning a property and deleting it directly again help achieve?

This looks like outsmarting some internal JS engine behaviour.

**EDIT**: As requested, here's the complete *out.js* as generated by *dart2js* (input is the "Hello world!" example from Wikipedia): https://gist.github.com/Blutkoete/59be155b2642832e9acd383df0857d02

**EDIT 2**: gurvinder372's link indicates is has to do with "delegating to anonymous JS objects for performance", but I'll probably need a lot of experience with JS to understand that.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28210

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense at all. It expects a parameter which is directly overridden - that's the first "error". And assigning a value to a property and deleting it thereafter doesn't change anything really. Maybe it's a leftover of code like `function map(x) { x = x || {}; }` which should make sure that a certain property is not set - but also then it wouldn't make sense to do that like that

Comment: can you reference the original code? @Blutkoete

Comment: @lustoykov Done.

Comment: It's a performance micro-optimisation. The function works the same as `function map() { return Object.create(null); }` would - it creates an empty object to be used as a lookup map.

Comment: Deleting a property will cause V8 to put the object into dictionary mode, but I’m not sure what the parameter is for. Maybe a leftover from minification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... This is an interesting topic and understanding this trick takes to read a little bit on the object representation of V8 compiler. I am not an expert on this but the topic was interesting enough to intrigue me to search for some answer. So here is what i have found.

First of all deleting a property seems to be a trick to change the internal structure of how object properties are kept and accessed. In other words deleting a property switches the object to dictionary mode where the properties are kept in a hash map. So when a dummy property is deleted immediately after it's created gives you an object in dictionary mode.

> V8 can handle minor divergences like this just fine, but if your code
>   assigns all sorts of random properties to objects from the same
>   constructor in no particular order, or if you delete properties, V8
>   will drop the object into dictionary mode, where properties are stored
>   in a hash table. This prevents an absurd number of maps from being
>   allocated.

Taken from this nice article [A tour of V8: object representation](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation)

Comment: Also, this question is interesting about pros and cons of dictionary mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455678/pros-and-cons-of-dictionary-mode