# Elegant way to transform certain property names in an array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Assume...

```
let A = [{ x:'x', y:'y' }, { x:'x', y:'y' }];
```

I know I can transform this array into a new one taking and renaming the `y` property like this...

```
A.map(o => ({ v: o.y }));
// [{ v:'y' }, { v:'y' }]
```

And I can use a spread to get all existing properties plus a new, transformed one like this...

```
A.map(o => ({ ...o, ...{ v: o.y } }));
// [{ x:'x', y:'y', v:'y' }, { x:'x', y:'y', v:'y' }]
```

But I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to simply rename the `y` property to `v`. So here's what I want.

```
// [{ x:'x', v:'y' }, { x:'x', v:'y' }]
```

I know I can use a function block on my fat arrow function, add a `v` property, and delete the `y` property, but that's cumbersome. I'm looking for something elegant.

Comment: How do you quantify "elegant"?

Comment: You tagged the question with ecmascript-6. Please note that "spread properties" are not part of ES6.

Comment: elegant = you know it when you see it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Array.map() and Object destructing :

```js
let A = [{ x:'x', y:'y' }, { x:'x', y:'y' }];

let result = A.map(({y,...rest})=> ({...rest,v:y}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyFoster Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could rename the property and use the rest syntax for an object to get all other properties. For mapping take the rested parameters and the new property.

```js
let A = [{ x: 'x', y: 'y' }, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }];

console.log(A.map(({ y: v, ...o }) => ({ ...o, v })));
```

Comment: I liked this more than the suggestion by @amrender singh

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you knew you could `delete`, but it doesn't necessarily have to be inelegant if you're looking to alter the objects in place:

```js
let A = [{ x:'x', y:'y' }, { x:'x', y:'y' }];

A.forEach(o => delete Object.assign(o, {v: o.y }).y)
console.log(A)
```

Comment: As an aside here, this will degrade performance on large sets due to delete triggering dictionary mode in most JavaScript engines. On small sets, this is clearly not an issue.

Comment: That's interesting @TravisJ, thanks — I didn't know that.

Comment: This made me curious @TravisJ, so I found [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455678/pros-and-cons-of-dictionary-mode) which pointed to [this jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/test-dictionary-mode). In the test `delete` is significantly slower in Safari, but the performance is essentially identical in Chrome. I wonder if recent changes to V8 have made this less significant.

Comment: That still uses delete, the perf is the same. Please see erfr of the 16th revision https://jsperf.com/test-dictionary-mode/17 for the comparison without delete. It is 32% faster.

Answer (score 0):

This approach provides a less ***hard-coded*** way to convert keys into new ones.  On the other hand, this `[mapping[k]]` is called [*`Computed property names`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed-property-names).

Likewise, the function [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is building the desired object according to the `mapping` and the specific object itself.

***Important:*** The function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is creating a new Array, basically is not modifying/mutating the original array.

```js
let A = [{ x:'x', y:'y' }, { x:'x', y:'y' }];
    mapping = {'y': 'v'},    
    result = A.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((a, k) => {
      if (k in mapping) return Object.assign(a, {[mapping[k]]: o[k]});
      return Object.assign(a, {[k]: o[k]});
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```